# Matlab 'bad file descriptor', deleting all processed data

Tags: matlab, mkdir

I have a folder where I have unprocessed data for my research. To process it, I run a script where it performs some operations and stores the data in a subfolder called "PC". I've never had an issue with this script, but I came back this morning to a strange error. Here's a snippet:

```
Performing calibration on file 1985 of 3802...
Performing calibration on file 1986 of 3802...
Performing calibration on file 1987 of 3802...

Error using mkdir
Bad file descriptor

Error in DriverScript17 (line 166)
        mkdir(PC_folder);
```

Ok, so it made it through the first 1986 files just fine, but then stopped working randomly. Not only that, it deleted the 1986 calibrated files it had already stored in /.../PC/, which is obviously an issue! By going to the PC subfolder through the terminal, when I try to open it, it says "-bash: cd: PC: bad file descriptor".

Here's the code where it threw an error:

```
if (conditions) == 1; %this is True for what I'm doing
    %% Perform operations on the data
    if ~exist(PC_folder);
        mkdir(PC_folder); % PC_folder = strcat(current_folder, 'PC/');
    end
    save(filename,'DATA');
end
```

I checked, and I should still have about 200 GB left of storage on my 2 TB external hard drive, so I doubt that's it. Any ideas?

Comment: What does `fopen('all')` return after you experience the problem? It is likely you forgot to close some file handles and simply exceeded the maximum number.

Comment: Since the same thing happened in the shell, this sounds like your filesystem freaked out, and MATLAB is showing you the same error as the shell does.  MATLAB isn't to blame, and neither is your code.  Keep backups.

Comment: @Daniel--I'm re-running it now, so I can't check. If it gives the same error again, I'll try fopen and check to make sure all file handles are being closed.

Comment: @Peter--Does that mean it could be my external hard drive possibly going bad, or a bad sector on the drive? I've got everything backed up, thankfully.

Comment: @Daniel fopen('all') returned [] (null set).